# android: fcm in library module

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am facing a weird issue integrating Firebase Cloud Messaging in a library module. I am working on a library project in which I need to handle notifications right coming from the FCM Server from the library itself. I am not aware if it is possible or not.

Steps I followed:

- I created Project on Firebase Console.
- Inside the project, I created app with package same as my library package.
- I downloaded and put `google-services.json` in library module.
- I have applied the dependency in gradle of library module.
- Now, I have initialized my library module in app module. I am also getting log of generated device token from `FirebaseInstanceIdService`.

**Problem:** When I try to send push from Firebase Console, I am not receiving any Notification.

Have anyone faced such issue and could help me with this ?

Comment: No, currently I am testing on Emulator. But I have tried with Moto G3 devices, still no success.

Comment: Are you sending data messages or notification messages? For data messages, you will have to show the notification from the app itself. Please refer this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options

Comment: @fightingCoder Yes I know that. I have put log lines in MessagingService, but I didn't find any logs.

Comment: How are you sending the messages? Using FCM registration token or android app package name?

Comment: Make sure you implement two services in your manifest.
MyFirebaseMessagingService and MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.
The first is generate and register push id and second one is handle your push notification.

Comment: @fightingCoder I am using App Package Name for pushing Notifications.

Comment: Did u try with the registeration token too?? Just give it a try.

Comment: @fightingCoder I tried.. No success..

Comment: Does it show success in the firebase console?

Comment: Hi Chintan. Does it not receive any messages when using the library or with the FCM messages itself? Could you test out if when using regularly with a simple app, if the messages are received? It'll help to pinpoint where the issue is. Cheers!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So, after running a lot through trial and error method, I succeeded in getting Notifications.

Things to be noted:

- You cannot just integrate Firebase Cloud Notifications in library module.
- Client app module who will be using this library module will have `google-services.json` file in his directory and not in library module directory.
- Client app module gradle will be having below line in it and not in library module gradle:

> apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

So, once I made those two changes, I was able to get Notifications.

Comment: I have same issue my library module has firebase login and in my app module i want to access it but package name is change so it give me error and i want to maintian the library module package name

Comment: @MuhammadYounas did you find any solution for this problem? 
thanks

Comment: You can add FCM in a library module by adding the core lib in the dependencies: `dependencies { compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.2.0' }` without the need to apply the gms services gradle plugin

Comment: i got error msg like "FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful"

Comment: When app module package is different with library module, I get No matching client found for package name blablabla

Comment: @Chintan Sony Did you use module package name while creating firebase project?

Comment: @Younas, did you find solution for this?

Comment: Has anyone checked other services based on FCM such as One Signal and PubNub working with android library?

Answer (score 0):

> FCM clients require devices running Android 2.3 or higher that also
>   have the Google Play Store app installed, or an emulator running
>   Android 2.3 with Google APIs.

If you are Using an Emulator Please Check whether Google APIs were installed or Not.

Answer (score -1):

Integrating FCM using Android Studio is very easy,
You have to only ,
Tool->>Firebase->>on the Right panel ->>Choose cloud Messaging.
Setup-->Firebase cloud messaging.

Then you have to follow point number 1,2,3.
And you have to also register your app to Firebase console also as you already status.