# Android: How to add FCM in a library project

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a library project in android. It is currently using GCM. The app that uses the project registers their gcm sender id and the project will generate a token from it and send it to the server and then listen to the GCM messages.

I want to upgrade my project to FCM. I was following the steps given [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm).

I am a little confused with the steps. My questions are:

1. Its asking me to get google-services.json file, which you can get by registering the app SHA value. I do not have an app in this case.
2. I need to implement the Service which will just listen to the FCM and do the relevant action but that is not clear from the document

Please help in how can I integrate FCM in a library project.

Thanks in advance.

Downvoting should be accompanied with the reason.

Comment: Could you check this tutorial? https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/firebase/firebase-cloud-messaging-tutorial/

Comment: The issue is, mine is a library porject and not an app. I cannot get the google-services.json file for that.

Comment: Can you provide the documentation for that?

Comment: I found an interesting link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43336975/android-fcm-in-library-module

Comment: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#0

Answer (score 0):

1. You need not add the google-services.json file in your SDK. The client app which integrates the SDK will need to do it.
2. Refer to [this](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging) example repo, this should clear out your confusion regarding implementing services